# Forcing minimum JPanel size

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to code a layout for a small phonebook app using Java Swing. I came across a problem with size I cannot fix. I want filters (displayed under search results) to be wide enough to show whole title when search phrase is short. Here's what it looks like:

[image: sample filters]

As you can see name is shortened. Surname is carrying longer text and is displayed just as I want.

**Filter class:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import java.awt.*;

public class Filter
{
    private JLabel label;
    private JPanel filterPane;

    Filter(String name)
    {
        // Filter text
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setForeground(new Color(0xAA0000));

        // Closing button
        JButton closeButton = new JButton("X");
        closeButton.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 20));
        closeButton.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));

        filterPane = new JPanel();
        filterPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(filterPane, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        // Frame with title + 50px padding on the right side for the next filter
        filterPane.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 50),
                BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(name)));
        filterPane.add(closeButton);
        filterPane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5, 0)));
        filterPane.add(label);
        filterPane.setVisible(false);
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty())
            filterPane.setVisible(false);
        else
        {
            this.label.setText(value);
            filterPane.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public JPanel getFilterPane() {
        return filterPane;
    }
}
```

**Main class:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class TestWindow
{
    private static void init()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stackoverflow test window");
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(480, 320));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        // Main panel - 20 px padding from each side
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        pane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

        // Create panel for filters
        JPanel filterPane = new JPanel();
        filterPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(filterPane, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        filterPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 60));

        // Add sample filters
        Filter filter = new Filter("name");
        filter.setValue("i");
        filter.getFilterPane().setAlignmentY(Component.BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT);
        filterPane.add(filter.getFilterPane());

        filter = new Filter("surname");
        filter.setValue("loooooong text");
        filter.getFilterPane().setAlignmentY(Component.BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT);
        filterPane.add(filter.getFilterPane());

        // Add everything to main panel
        pane.add(new JTextArea("Nothing fancy here, just to fill out space"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pane.add(filterPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setContentPane(pane);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) throws InterruptedException, InvocationTargetException {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(TestWindow::init);
    }
}
```

I tried `setMinimumSize` and `setPreferredSize` both for `label` and `filterPane` in Filter constructor, but it didn't help. Could you help me please?

Comment: How are you adding the panes to the parent window? What layout are you using? Please [edit] the question and add the applicable code.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. Done.

Comment: Instead of setting sizes, override the `getXxxSize` of the class. Post a [mcve].

Comment: [`JComponent.setMinimumSize`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setMinimumSize-java.awt.Dimension-), tried that?

Comment: Yes, both for filterPane and label. Didn't work.
@user1803551 You mean rewrite my question applying those rules?

Comment: @PKua Write a small (minimal) program that reproduces the issue, all in one class, that people can copy/paste and fiddle around with in their own programming environment. That's what's meant by MCVE or SSCCE.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I mean. We want to be able to copy-paste the code into our IDEs, run it and see the problem.

Comment: @user1803551 Thanks, done, tried to do my best. I hope everything is clear now.

Comment: So the problem is with the title border. A simple search gives previous questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407897/title-truncation-in-jpanel-titledborder-java-swing), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36405080/why-is-my-titled-border-panel-so-small), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260484/java-swing-how-to-change-the-font-size-on-a-jpanels-titledborder), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744611/title-collapse-in-titledborder) and an openJDK report [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4994231).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is actually composed of two problems.

1. When using `TitledBorder`, the component does not take the size of the title into account when calculating its preferred size.
2. When using `BoxLayout`, the preferred width is ignored, unless you add "horizontal glue" after the component.

So, to fix the first problem, you need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of JPanel. But for this to work, you also need to bypass the second problem by adding glue.

To override the `getPreferredSize()`, you can use something like:

```
class MinSizePanel extends JPanel {

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension original = super.getPreferredSize();
        TitledBorder titleBorder = (TitledBorder)((CompoundBorder)getBorder()).getInsideBorder();
        int width = (int)Math.max( original.getWidth(), 60 + (int)titleBorder.getMinimumSize(this).getWidth());
        return new Dimension( width, (int)original.getHeight() );
    }
}
```

This gets the `TitledBorder` from the `CompoundBorder`, gets its minimum size (this is a method that takes the title width into consideration), adds some extra for the empty border and insets (you can add the appropriate calculations, I did a shortcut and just used `60`...), and uses that (if it's more than the width of the component as-is).

Instead of

```
filterPane = new JPanel();
```

Use

```
filterPane = new MinSizePanel();
```

(You should really move all the rest of the construction of the panel into that class as well).

And in the `TestWindow` class, after the last

```
    filterPane.add(filter.getFilterPane());
```

Also add

```
    filterPane.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved the problem. So `BoxLayout` ignores the preferred width of the container it's bound to unless there is a glue as well?

Comment: @PKua It ignores the preferred width of the components, not the preferred width of the container. I think it is trying to make the layout compact, like a line of text that's justified to the left. Adding the glue causes it to calculate a different max width and change its policy. There could be other ways to achieve the same effect.